# Continuously receive data from socket and reading selected data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, sockets

I want to read a weighing machine socket and update its value in GUI.

The socket will send the current weight value continuosly. 
My data (weight) will be less than 100 bytes.

If i give buffer as 100, its taking too much time to update the current value as it has to read all the remaining bytes.  So, I changed buffer size to 4096 bytes. Now the value is updating Real Time.

My question is,
--- Is giving 4096 bytes is really a great overhead in performance (when compared to 100 bytes)??
--- Is  it possible to read clear all the available data and just read last 100 bytes when ever a message is received??

The code I am using for Call Back:

```
   private void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            try
            {
                //Get received bytes count
                var bytesRead = _clientSocket.EndReceive(ar);
                if (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    //Copy received bytes to a new byte array
                    var receivedBytes = new byte[ReceiveBufferSize];

                    Array.Copy(_buffer, 0, receivedBytes, 0, 100); //100 byte is enough for checking the data

                    FormatAndUpdateGUI(receivedBytes);

                }
                else
                {
                    throw new Exception("Error in Reading");
                }
        //Read more bytes 
                    _clientSocket.BeginReceive(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), null);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
               throw new Exception("Error in Reading");
            }
        }
```

Comment: putting a `throw new Exception("...")` in a `catch` block is pretty pointless. You just threw away the *actual* exception. I recommend either passing `ex` to the constructor of the exception you're throwing (it becomes `InnerException`), or for this case, just remove the whole outer `try/catch`.

Comment: if `bytesRead > 0`, there's **no** guarantee that it equals 100.

Answer (score 1):

You should always be reading in `bytesRead`, so that you read the maximum available data at any given time. In this case you can also optimize your memory usage by using a `byte` array of size `bytesRead` so that it exactly matches what you need and not some predefined maximum.